# check the given listbox item string is selected or not?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, listbox

Ill give the input string name like 'Antony'. That string was listbox item and its also selected. How can i check whether the given string is selected or not with in a single search.

]If its possible means please post the sample code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private bool Search(string value)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        foreach (ListItem listItem in ListBox1.Items)
        {
           if (listItem.Selected && listItem.ToString() == value)
            {
               ret = true;
               break;

            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

check using this function ...

OR

using LINQ

```
private bool Search(string value)
    {
        return ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Any(listItem => listItem.Selected && listItem.ToString() == value);
    }
```

Comment: I just use Multiple listbox item.I want to select more than one item what i do?